# Ultra low-latency in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: matlab, nvidia, low-latency, ubuntu-22.04, time-precision

I should run a visual experimental project with Matlab or Python in which the time resolution is dramatically important! that's why I shift to Linux and use the **low-latency kernel** in ubuntu. but I thought there is an **ultra-low-latency** or something like that in Linux Nvidia settings, same as a thing in 3D acceleration in Nvidia control panel windows.

Is there any way that enables Nvidia ultra-low latency in ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: We need a bit more information. Have you proven to yourself that any latency is because of Ubuntu or the Nvidia drivers?  I don't think anyone would describe Matlab or Python as low latency - these are great tools but not necessarily speedy.  Where are you seeing slowdowns?  Where do they come from?

Comment: I use Psychtoolbox(Matlab toolbox) to present visual stimuli on a monitor and I need a precision duration in the order of milliseconds. Actually time stamp precision of the Matlab functions is not satisfying. also, I think I need the variable refresh rate for this task which requires pre-rendered frames rapidly.

Answer (score 1):

Low latency kernel has very little to do with low latency in the sense of speed. low latency means only that your sound/video buffers will be serviced before they run out of data.

If what you need is complete control of the CPU during your experiment, you should use a tickless kernel, which Ubuntu does NOT provide and run your experiment on isolated CPUs. Also you should get a non-preemptable kernel (server).

Coincidentally I just wrote an article about those last week.

https://lucisqr.substack.com/p/compiling-a-tickless-kernel-on-ubuntu